# Countif list of list - list comprehension

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I would like to iterate over the values in the list `Dates` and first append the count of items in `Date_Values[0]` less than the value in `Date` then append the count of items in `Date_Values[1]` less than the value in `Date`

import datetime

```
Dates_Values = [['10-12-2014','11-1-2014'],['10-18-2014','10-26-2014']]
Dates = [['10-14-2014'],['10-19-2015']]

for key, item in enumerate(Dates):
    Dates[key].append(sum(1 for item in Dates_Values if datetime.datetime.strptime(str(item[0]), '%m-%d-%Y') > (datetime.datetime.strptime(str(item[0]), '%m-%d-%Y'))))
    Dates[key].append(sum(1 for item in Dates_Values if datetime.datetime.strptime(str(item[1]), '%m-%d-%Y') > (datetime.datetime.strptime(str(item[1]), '%m-%d-%Y'))))

print Dates
```

Output:

```
[['10-14-2014', 0, 0], ['10-19-2015', 0, 0]]
```

Desired Results:

```
[['10-14-2014',1,0],['10-19-2015',2,2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

It helps to simplify your code a bit. The single best thing you can do here is to notice that you use this invocation:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(arg, '%m-%d-%Y')
```

four times, and all that changes is the value of `arg`. So put it in a function:

```
def parse_date(datestamp):
   return datetime.datetime.strptime(str(datestamp), '%m-%d-%Y')
```

You can also sum bools directly instead of using the awkward `sum(1 for item in ...)`. Putting them together you get this:

```
for key, item in enumerate(Dates):
    Dates[key].append(sum(parse_date(item[0]) > parse_date(item[0]) for item in Dates_Values))
    Dates[key].append(sum(parse_date(item[1]) > parse_date(item[1]) for item in Dates_Values))
```

This makes your bug much easier to spot: the things you're comparing are the same, and hence will always be *equal*. You seem to be confusing yourself by reusing the name `item` in both the outer loop and the generator expressions - you are expecting the left-hand side of each comparison to use the outer `item`, and the right to use the inner one. You *can* get away with this by parsing the outer date out first (which is a good idea anyway), but it is better to avoid shadowing the variable like this because you won't *always* be able to do that. Also, since `Dates[key]` is just `item` in the outer loop, you actually don't need to use `enumerate` at all:

```
for item in Dates:
    date = parse_date(item[0])

    item.append(sum(date > parse_date(i[0]) for i in Dates_Values))
    item.append(sum(date > parse_date(i[1]) for i in Dates_Values))
```

---

Also, Python convention is that variable and function names should be all lower-case - ie, `dates` rather than `Dates` etc; initial capitals are reserved for class names. This doesn't affect how your code works in the slightest, but it can make it easier for you and others to read.

Comment: thanks for the useful comments....I am getting `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` om the first append line

Comment: It works now. I see my error now that I am comparing the same thing, but how to do I directly compare my reference date in `Dates` with each item in `Date_Values`? I'm new to Python and am having trouble wrapping my head around it.

Comment: @thanks this is starting to make sense. Were does the `i` come from?

Comment: @user2242044 the `for i in...` part of a generator expression exactly mimics the semantics of a for loop (it is *not* a coincidence that they look nearly identical) - ie, you can use any valid variable name there.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, we want to transform every element of `Dates`. So that tells us we want to start with:

```
Dates = [f(d) for d in Dates]
```

From there we can either just build up what `f` is:

```
def count(d, idx):
    return sum(1 for item in Dates_Values if ...) # use item[idx] where
                                                  # you had item[0], item[1]

Dates = [[d, count(d, 0), count(d, 1)] for d in Dates]
```

We could of course write the definition of `count` inline, kind of the way you had it, but that to me is much less readable:

```
Dates = [[d] + [sum(1 for item in Dates_Values if...) for idx in (0,1)]
         for d in Dates]
```

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit new to Python and am not following this. I try to put it together and keep getting syntax errors.

Comment: Error is `NameError: name 'f' is not defined`

Comment: @user2242044 That was intended to be a model for what the solution would look like. The answer goes on to provide what kinds of things `f` might be.

Comment: pretty new to python and I don't really understand functions to well. Tried replacing f with count to no avail.